# Firefox absolute position is positioning outside of parent container and in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, firefox

It's odd, but IE8 is currently handling my layout better than FF. With Firefox every absolute positioned element is centering to the middle of the page, instead of centering to It's parent, which do you have classes position:absolute; and position:relative; - this is happening to several things on my layout. The layout works perfect in Chrome/IE8+.

Any known fixes or any similar issues for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code in your post and appreciatively on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent element has

```
position: relative
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGv5S/):

```
#red{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#blue{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

<div id="red">
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for that. Unfortunately I already have the parent elements classed correctly. It's a problem I've never come across before.